# Le mot "ébat" dans un contexte judiciaire

Tags: sens, droit-et-justice

J'ai eu la surprise de trouver dans une correspondance avec un magistrat le mot "ébat".

Pour moi ce mot a une connotation fortement péjorative en première lecture. Cependant vu l'insolence que cela impliquerait de la part de l'auteur et l'absence claire de raison de me rabaisser en dehors de l'arrogance, j'aimerais en avoir le cœur net, imaginant un possible sens caché propre au contexte judiciaire dont on connaît les particularités de langage.

Donc la phrase est la suivante, modifiée uniquement pour des raisons de confidentialité:

« Je peux parfaitement comprendre que vous souhaitiez l'assistance d'un avocat dans un ébat qui selon vous, dépasse largement l’objet de la demande de conciliation de [nom de la personne à l'origine de la demande]. »

Cette phrase apparaît en réponse à mon propre courrier dans lequel j'explique que la demande de conciliation formulée par la partie adverse n'a pas un motif déclaré en phase avec la réalité de l'affaire, et que si conciliation doit avoir lieu, elle doit aborder l'ensemble des griefs, et que j'entends me faire assister d'un avocat.

L'autre explication possible, à laquelle je viens tout juste de penser, et qui se trouverait justifiée par le nombre considérable de fautes de frappe que compte son courrier ainsi que par la nature des échanges entre les parties pendant la conciliation avant de trouver un accord amiable, c'est qu'il ait voulu écrire débat au lieu d'ébat.

Comment: *C'est qu'il ait voulu écrire **débat** au lieu **d'ébat*** : Ça passe mieux à l'écrit ;-)

Comment: Comme j'écris plus bas à LPH, c'est de moins en moins certain.

Comment: You missed the joke...

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement, je ne vois aucunement une connotation péjorative dans cet emploi, et cela parce que ce qui est à voir par dessus tout c'est l'impropriété de ce terme: il ne convient tout simplement pas, il faut s'en tenir à la définition, laquelle comprendrait certainement toute acception juridique; ce n'est pas le cas. Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9bats) définit « ébat » ainsi.

> Gén. au plur. [Appliqué le plus souvent aux enfants] Jeu, divertissement qui consiste à se livrer à des mouvements folâtres exprimant la joie de vivre. Ébats enfantins, puérils. Prendre ses ébats. Se divertir (généralement en plein air) en folâtrant et en gambadant.

Mis à part une spécialisation à la chasse et une à la mécanique il n'y a pas d'autres possibilité.

Cependant, on trouve le terme « [débats](https://www.dictionnaire-juridique.com/definition/debats.php) » dans le droit privé.

> Les "débats" constituent la partie orale de la procédure menée, selon le cas, en audience publique ou en Chambre du Conseil au cours de laquelle les avocats et, dans les affaires communicables, éventuellement le Procureur de la République, développent les moyens et les défenses qu'ils ont déjà exprimés dans leurs conclusions. La clôture des débats marque le moment où l'affaire est mise en délibéré.

Il y a peu de doute que le d a été omis par erreur (faute de frappe).

Comment: Je trouve la seconde partie de votre réponse plus convaincante que la première. Comparer une façon de s'exprimer à des ébats ("mouvements folâtres") n'est pas aussi invraisemblable que vous l'affirmez. En tout cas merci de votre contribution.

Comment: @Exocytosis Dans ma première partie je veux seulement exprimer le fait, comme on dit assez vulgairement, que ce mot arrive comme un cheveux sur la soupe dans une communication telle que celle-ci ; c'est tout simplement du non sens. Se permettre une telle liberté que de forcer des insinuations aussi hors de propos ne peut pas être le fait d'un homme de loi, à moins qu'il soit devenu fou. Je dois ajouter qu'il n'y a pas de place pour la poésie dans des communications de cette sorte.

Comment: Difficile de faire plus clair que votre dernier commentaire! Vous m'avez entièrement convaincu. Merci de ces clarifications et de votre aide.

Comment: En fait je retire ce que j'ai dit. Dans son message suivant cet individu est incontestablement insultant.

Comment: @Exocytosis Chose qui me rend très curieux; c'est si surprenant!

Comment: Et surtout désolant.